# Geolocation search with Gremlin

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Is it possible to do a location search in Gremlin? I can't see how it can be done in [the documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/). I specifically want to do the location search in Cosmos Gremlin.

Answer (score 3):

Geo location currently is something that is provided by the back end graph system. For example JanusGraph has a GeoSpatial API that can be used with Gremlin. Of course if you store lat/lon coordinates in your graph you can pretty easily write a Gremlin query to use those to look for things based on coordinates.

I have a few examples of doing it manually in section 5.3.8 of the Gremlin tutorial I am writing. Available here: https://github.com/krlawrence/graph

Answer (score 0):

There's also a nice **Azure Cosmos DB - Graph Api** application demo created by **Antony Chu** which practically does that.

https://github.com/anthonychu/cosmosdb-gremlin-flights

The application is mainly built in 2 parts

-A **Console Application** which defines **Airport** object model - **Code**, **Name**, **GeoCoordinate Coordinate**... and generates **long/lat** coordinates nodes as **Vertex**.

-An **Asp.NET MVC** Web application which mainly uses a **Bing Map** in UI to display **Airport** nodes from **Vertex** coordinates and defines linked routes
through **Edges** parameters in **GetRoutes** function. Hope this helps.