# Measure GPS distance between two points without using almost any math? (accuracy is not needed at all)

Tags: math, geolocation, gps, gremlin, google-geolocation

I'm programming an application where I save GPS location (lat and long) into each user info. I need to search the nearest users, I can only search using a between() function provided by my database, this function only checks if a number is between a range min and max, it's a very limited tool.

Can I use this to find near users?

This is a pseudo-code example of what I could do, this example finds users that their lat and long values are not more or less than 2 comparing with the target user:

```
lon.is(between(user.lon - 2, user.lon + 2).and(
lat.is(between(user.lat - 2, user.lat + 2))
```

I don't care about accuracy, I only want to get the closest users in maximum distance of like a city size approximately, that is all I need.

Is this going to work? I'm not familiar with geolocation math and coordinate problems in general.

When I store the GPS data I can convert the data into another format using all the math required without problems, so a coordinte system convertion is available, but for searching I can only use that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the differences in latitude and longitude in decimal degrees, you can do a quick calculation for distance.

Considering the mean Earth radius to be 6,371 km, meaning that each degree covers approximately:

```
                          (2*pi*6371)/360 = 111.19 Km,
```

all you have to do is to take the resultant of the latitude and longitude differences as:

```
                        sqrt((lat1-lat2)^2 + (lon1-lon2)^2),
```

and multiply it for 119.19 to have the distance in Km.

This is a very rough calculation as you requested, but should be enough if we're talking about city-level precision.

Update:

Your pseudocode would look like this:

```
    #City radius in Km
    city_radius = 60 

    #City radius in degrees
    city_radius_degree = 60/111.19

    lon.is.NOT(between(user.lon - city_radius_degree, user.lon + city_radius_degree).or(
    lat.is.NOT(between(user.lat - city_radius_degree, user.lat + city_radius_degree))
```

You're checking if, in any direction, the users are within the same circle. See that I changed the query from and to or, since both don;t have to be true at the same time for the distance to be above a certain threshold.

Again, this is a very rough approximation, but probably good enough for your intentions.

Comment: I don't understand the first algorithm, is it for converting lar or long into Km? what is 6371? is the lat or lon decimal degree? Is that similar to this?: https://www.usna.edu/Users/oceano/pguth/md_help/html/approx_equivalents.htm

About the second algorithm you posted is something I cannot do in my program, only compare numbers like in the pseudo code I posted

Comment: Yes, this is the procedure to convert lat and long into Km in a very rough way. What you can do in this case is to do the inverse of that algorithm. If you're looking into assessing if two points are apart 50 Km, for example, you can calculate how much would it represent in decimal degrees. 1 Km, as an example, would be (1/119.19) which is equal to approximately  0.0084 degrees. For 50 Km, you have (50/119.19) which is approximately 0.42 degrees. For 200 Km, 1.68 degrees and so on...

Comment: I wrote an update with how your pseudocode would look like.

Comment: Great! but I'm not sure about the "or" change you made, what if user1 is at the same lat but lon is 50 degrees of distance? it will take it as close but it's very far right? The same happens with X Y coordinate system, same X is not close if Y is too far, am I wrong?

Comment: You're right. It should be a not.between, and or. If that's possible. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Gremlin does support complex math calculations using the `math` step.

For simplicity I used the [Equirectangular approximation formula](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html):

```
x = Δλ ⋅ cos φm
y = Δφ
d = R ⋅ √x² + y²
```

To get the distance between user (id = 0) and her connected users, assuming GPS coordinates are stored in Degrees, you can use this query:

```
g.V(0).as("ln1","lt1").out().as("ln2","lt2")
 .math("sqrt (((ln2 - ln1) * 3.141 / 180 * cos ((lt1 + lt2) * 3.141 / 360))^2 + ((lt2 - lt1) * 3.141 / 180)^2) * 6371")
 .by("lon").by("lon").by("lat").by("lat")
```

Where 3.141 stands for PI, and 6371 is the average radius of earth (in km).

If GPS values were stored in Radians (`R = D * PI / 180`) it becomes much cleaner:

```
g.V(0).as("ln1","lt1").out().as("ln2","lt2")
 .math("sqrt (((ln2 - ln1) * cos ((lt1 + lt2) / 2))^2 + (lt2 - lt1)^2) * 6371")
 .by("lon").by("lon").by("lat").by("lat")
```

Finally, to get only those within a specific distance (i.e. 20km), you can append `.is(lt(20))` to the query. To get the users vertices you can move the `math` step inside a `where` step.

Comment: What do you think about the solution I posted in my question?. I know gremlin supports your solution but I was looking for the solution that has the better performance

Comment: Have you checked performance of math? I don't think it will have great impact. In your solution you get a "rectangle" and not a circle, so it is not the same distance like you requested.  If you store the GPS coordinates in Radians,  the math becomes relatively simple.